# Entity reference, display custom field, not the title

Tags: entities

I am using drupal 8.
I have two content types:

ORGANIZATION with the following fields
- Title
- image logo
- much more fields

EVENT
- Title
- Start Date
- End Date
- Reference to the organizations (unlimited)

The event page needs to display the title of the event, start date, end date and all the logos of the organisations (not the titles of the organizations)
How can I do this ?

In the "Manage Display" of the fields in the Event type, in the "Format" there are only 3 options, "Rendered Entity", "Entity ID", "Label". For "rendered entity" there are a few options as "Default", "Full content" and some other. But I cannot see an option to specify only to display the logo.

Comment: Here is the anwser https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235693/display-hierarchical-entity-reference-fields-inside-node

Answer (score 0):

Create a view and set the filter "Content: Type", to "one of"- Event and Organization. Pull all the fields you want to be displayed and publish the view in a page or as a block on any page. You can further customize the html of said created view per the instructions [here](http://redcrackle.com/blog/drupal-8/theme-views-templates) :)

Comment: Is this for a list of events, or the event itself? Because I need it for the event, not the list of events