# Display hierarchical entity reference fields inside node

Tags: 8, entities

I have the following content types in Drupal 8 :

**User**

- field: image
- other fields

**Organization**

- field: logo
- Entity reference to User [one to many]
- other fields

**Event**

- Field: Date
- Field: Description
- Entity reference to Organization [one to many]

**The event nodes need to look like this (display the following):**

- Event Title
- Event Date
- Event Description
- All the organization logos (from the organizations added as a reference entity to the event)
- All the user logos that belong to the already referenced organizations

Is there any way to do this with already existing Drupal 8 modules or do I have to write some custom code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could render this with four different display modes:

1.) The Event view mode to start with:

- Event Title
- Event Date
- Event Description
- Reference field for Organization, configured to render the view mode `logos1`
- Reference field for Organization, configured to render the view mode `logos2`

2.) The Organization view mode `logos1` contains one field for the Organization logos:

- Image field logos

3.) The Organization view mode `logos2` contains one field for the User logos

- Reference field for the content type User, configured to render the view mode `userlogos`

4.) The content type User view mode `userlogos`

- Image field for user logos

To implement two instances of the reference field you need the module Display Suite. Or combine logo1 and logos2 in one view mode with two fields, but then the logos will get mixed. Or use for the second reference field a View, with the help of [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva).

Comment: So clear and precise answer :)